# How can I bring calc.exe to the front?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, sony-vaio

I have the following code assigned to a [VAIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaio#Sony_VAIO_(1996_to_2014)) button:

```
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

But each time I press the VAIO button, I get a new instance of the calculator in a new window. What would be the command line that brings the calculator to front if there is already a window of it?

BTW: I tried the following, but it didn't work. It just
behaves as the VAIO button:

```
start /B calc       # Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3):

The batch file to check if `calc.exe` is already started doesn't have to be as elaborate as *uprego* stated.

But first... Do you really want to **switch** to the **current** `calc.exe`? Or do you just want one `calc.exe` running. If you don't need to switch to the current one you can just make a batch file which kills the first and runs a new instance of `calc.exe`:

`calc.bat`:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im "calc.exe"
start calc.exe
```

The only downside is you lose the current result in your previous calculation.

If you don't want the current `calc.exe` to be killed there are also solutions to bring it to the front (but they will be somewhat more complicated). Let me know if you really want to switch to the current `calc.exe` and I'll try to do some further searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with AutoHotkey and this script:

```
<yourkey>::
IfWinExist Calculator
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    else
    {
        Run calc.exe
        WinWait Calculator
        WinActivate
    }
```

The only thing here is to modify `<yourkey>` with the code of your VAIO button. To find it:

- right click on the autohotkey icon in the tray
- choose open
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (or select `Key History and Script Info` in the `View` menu)
- press your VIAO button, then <kbd>F5</kbd>.

At the bottom, on the second column, you'll find the SC code of the button. Replace `<yourkey>` by `SCxxx` (so `SC123` if your SC code was 123).

Answer (score 0):

You can build a more elaborated Microsoft batch script and assign it to the VAIO button. This script can:

- Check a flag file in the temporal files folder.

  - If it exists, bring the window visible in the screen if it's running, else open the program.
  - If it does not exist, create it, open the program and wait for termination, then delete the flag file.

To me here the unresolved primitives would be *create temporal file*, *find program by process name* and *bring the window visible in the scren*. Those should be easy to find in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or the Internet in general.

Comment: If I check SO I find for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557166/bring-to-front-for-windows-xp-command-shell

Comment: What is "the temporal files folder"?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mighta meant "a" or "some" temporal files folder. Should I edit this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut for calc.exe and place it anywhere on your hard drive, then call this shortcut from your hot key, you do not even need a batch. Windows will take care of it for you. Alas, if there is an open calc.exe it will be shown. So your C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe call would be C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe.lnk given you place the .lnk file in C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Some claim it will not work on later versions of Windows: A new instance of calc.exe will be launched instead.